# After executing the query, cardinality estimate warning gets displayed

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 1 D2.EMAIL_Address As SupervisorSId
        , D2.Employee_ID As SupervisorId
        , COALESCE(D2.DISPLAY_NAME,D2.First_Name + ' ' +D2.Last_Name,'') AS  [By_Assignee_Supervisor] 
        , D1.Manager_LDAP_Path,d2.SHORT_USER_NAME 
        , D1.JOB_TITLE
        , D1.DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM [Departments].[DBO].[DEPARTMENT_STRUCTURE_EMPLOYEE_MASTER] D1 
Inner Join [Departments].[DBO].[MANAGER_CONFIG] M1 ON CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),D1.Employee_GUID)=CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),M1.Employee_GUID)
        --AND D1.Short_User_Name= CC.[CASE_ASSGN_TO]    
Inner Join [Departments].[DBO].[DEPARTMENT_STRUCTURE_EMPLOYEE_MASTER] D2 ON CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),D2.Employee_GUID)=CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),M1.MANAGER_GUID)
INNER JOIN [Departments].[DBO].[USER_ACCOUNT_STATUS_REF] UASR WITH(NOLOCK) ON D1.USER_AD_STATUS =UASR.STATUS_VALUE  
ORDER BY M1.IS_Primary DESC
```

I have this query with me. On executing, it is showing warning on the left hand side desktop.

[image]
[Full-size version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coBDw.png)

Can anyone please tell me how to remove this warning?

Comment: You are not getting an error, but a warning.  In particular, you should be avoiding conversions in `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: Thank you Gordon

Comment: Hi Gordon. After removing the convert function, still I am getting the same warning.

Comment: @DipeshBhambhani please post the query without the conversion. You have 2 joins with conversions on both sides. Posting the tables DDL will help with a fix also.

Comment: Start over and top using the bad habits you have picked up. Why do you convert to nvarchar(max) columns that should be defined as GUID? That serves no purpose. If those columns are not defined as GUID, then you have even larger issues to resolve. And you can convert a GUID into a fixed length string - nvarchar(max) is a vast overkill. Nor is sprinkling nolock hints in your code some magic speed booster. You join to UASR but don't use it in your resultset - why?

Comment: @SMor this is just a part of code which is showing this warning. I am optimizing this part of query and I found this warning.